# Values correctly assigned when called from inside function body, failing while pytest run

Tags: python, pytest

There is this simple code:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict


temperatures = [10, 20, 35, 50]
feels = 'cold warm hot extreme'.split()
scopes = zip(temperatures, feels)

def get_feel(temperature):
    od = OrderedDict()
    for i in range(0, 10):
        od[i] = None

    for s in list(scopes):
        for i in range(s[0], 121):
            od[i] = s[1]

    return od.get(temperature)
```

Running printout right before the `return` clause, like:

```py
for o in od.items():
    print(o)
```

results in:

```
(0, None)
(1, None)
(2, None)
(3, None)
(4, None)
(5, None)
(6, None)
(7, None)
(8, None)
(9, None)
(10, 'cold')
(11, 'cold')
(12, 'cold')
[...]
```

Also, calling `od[temperature]` before `return` clause gives correct output as well.

However, `pytest` run reports errors on this:

```py
import pytest

from feel import get_feel


@pytest.mark.parametrize("input_argument, expected_return", [
    (0, None),
    (9, None),
    (10, 'cold'),
    (34, 'warm'),
    (35, 'hot')
])
def test_get_feel(input_argument, expected_return):
    assert get_feel(input_argument) == expected_return
```

Errors:

```
input_argument = 10, expected_return = 'cold'
[...]
    def test_get_feel(input_argument, expected_return):
>       assert get_feel(input_argument) == expected_return
E       AssertionError: assert None == 'cold'
[...]
```

What is actually wrong with that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the way your code is structured. Particularly, the line

```
scopes = zip(temperatures, feels)
```

which is in the global scope. The first time `get_feel` is called, all of your keys in `od` are set correctly (try changing your first test to be `(10, 'cold')` or any other correct value and you'll see.) However, in any subsequent call, the `scopes` generator has already been exhausted during the first function call. Thus only keys `0-10` will have values. Moving that line to the first line of `get_feel`, i.e.

```
def get_feel(temperature):
    scopes = zip(temperatures, feels)
    od = OrderedDict()
```

works but is klunky. The real issue is that since `od` always contains the same values it should be created once and passed via a new parameter or, in the interest of time, could just be created at the global scope.